# JDBC connection error

Tags: jdbc, glassfish

I have created a JDBC Connection Pool in Glassfish and use it as a JDBC Resource "jdbc/__default". I can ping this connection pool successfully in the Administration Console interface.

Then, I am trying to run the following program:

```
package de.java2enterprise.onlineshop;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@WebServlet("/test")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // @Resource(name="jdbc/__default")
    // private DataSource ds;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        writer.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        writer.println("<html><body>");

        Connection con = null;
        DataSource ds;
        try {

            ds = (DataSource) InitialContext.doLookup("jdbc/__default");
            con = ds.getConnection();

            if (con.isValid(10)) {
                writer.println("<BR>Connected!");
            }
            con.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            writer.println(ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (con != null){
                try{
                    con.close();
                } catch (Exception ex){

                }
            }
        }
        writer.println("<BR>Test finished!</body></html>");
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

However, then I receive the following error in the web browser:

> Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12518, TNS:listener could not hand off client connection 
>   Test finished!

In the server log, I get the following error:

> 2015-04-08T08:15:20.540+0200|Information: Loading application [onlineshop#onlineshop-war.war] at [onlineshop-war]
>   2015-04-08T08:15:20.636+0200|Information: onlineshop was successfully deployed in 611 milliseconds.
>   2015-04-08T08:15:38.552+0200|Warnung: Context path from ServletContext: /onlineshop-war differs from path from bundle: onlineshop-war
>   2015-04-08T08:15:38.802+0200|Information: visiting unvisited references
>   2015-04-08T08:15:39.519+0200|Information: Successfully got INSTRUMENTATION: sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl@2d618042
>
> 2015-04-08T08:15:41.471+0200|Warnung: RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool Onlineshop. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
>   ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack
>
> 2015-04-08T08:15:41.471+0200|Warnung: RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ Onlineshop ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
>   ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack
>
> 2015-04-08T08:15:41.486+0200|Warnung: RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
>   ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack
>    ]

After that, I can not ping the connection pool again and receive more or less the same error in the Administration Console.

I use the following configuration: *JDK 1.8.0_25, GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 (build 13), Oracle Database XE 11.2*.

In Glassfish administration console, I've created the following JDBC Resource: *JNDI Name: jdbc/__default, Logical JNDI Name: java:comp/DefaultDataSource, Connection Pool: Onlineshop*. 
The JDBC Connection Pool Name is *Onlineshop, Resource Type: javax.sql.DataSource, Classname: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource*.

I've a minimal pool size of 800 connections, maximum of 3200 connections. The other parameters I've kept as they were, I've only added user and password at JDBC Connection Pool Properties.

Anyone an idea? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close your connection in a [finally block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) or in [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) if you use jdk7+ as it should be done in Java. See if it helps

Comment: Hi jjd, thank you! I've added the following to my code, but that didn't work:
`finally {
   if (con != null){
    try{
     con.close();
     writer.close();
    } catch (Exception ex){
     
    }
   }
  }`

Comment: Can you, pls, update the code with the changes you made, also provide more info like what DB you use, what driver, the connection pool settings

Comment: I've added information above. Anything still missing?

Comment: silly question: you have oracle driver in the domain lib folder, right?

Comment: You can check your values with what official documentation states http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/gkyan.html. This one is for v3.1, but I believe it works for current version. You also may want to recreate your pool with the commands from the doc and see if it helps. You also may want to double check if the user you use has permission to access the DB

Comment: In general, you may face this behavior when the connections from a pool are not handled properly. Even if you set quite big values for connections number it could drained out pretty quickly. I have never tried values that big though and I am not sure if it makes sense. BTW(unrelated to the problem) note you still have your connection closed inside try block. There is no need for this anymore. It is closed inside finally block.

Comment: Being a micro manager: I would not leave the catch block empty when the connection is closed. Once there is a problem in this place, you have no way to see it. It would not appear in a log file or re-thrown to the client code. It will be just swallowed. Also writer should be treated the same way as you did for connection ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for the late answer! I solved the issue by making the pool size and the number of connections smaller, as you proposed. Thanks again!